# Как получить boolean используя RxJava2?

Tags: rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Вот есть такой метод

```
private boolean checkIfQuestionIsDisableCheckbox(ServicePartFormQuestion iQuestion)
{
    boolean result = true;

    if (iQuestion.getAnswerFieldType().isCheckbox())
    {
        eCheckBoxState state = getCheckBoxState(iQuestion.getQuestionId());
        result = !state.isDisable();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Я хочу его переписать используя rx

получилось вот так

```
private boolean checkIfQuestionIsDisableCheckbox(ServicePartFormQuestion iQuestion)
{
    return Observable.just(iQuestion)//
                     .filter(question -> question.getAnswerFieldType().isCheckbox())//
                     .map(question -> getCheckBoxState(question.getQuestionId()))//
                     .map(state -> !state.isDisable())//
                     .blockingFirst();
}
```

Но все перестает работать когда после этой операции

```
.filter(question -> question.getAnswerFieldType().isCheckbox())//
```

ничего не остается

и

```
 .blockingFirst();
```

получает ошибку что такого элементак нет

Как правильно написать этот метод?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [blockingFirst](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingFirst-T-) может возвращать значение по умолчанию, если `Observable` ничего не предоставил:

```
return Observable.just(iQuestion)
                 .filter(question -> question.getAnswerFieldType().isCheckbox())
                 .map(question -> getCheckBoxState(question.getQuestionId()))
                 .map(state -> !state.isDisable())
                 .blockingFirst(true);
```

Comment: Не подумал совсем, что там есть дефолтное значение. А вот еще вопрос по Rx можете подсказать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806607/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-rxjava2