# Как сделать итерацию с индексом в RxJava2?

Tags: rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Вот есть у меня такой метод, который я хочу переписать с Rx

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getAllQuestionsPositionsByType(eQuestionFieldType iType)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ServicePartFormQuestion> questions = getVisibleQuestions();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < questions.size() ; i++)
    {
        ServicePartFormQuestion tmp = questions.get(i);
        eQuestionFieldType type = tmp.getQuestionFieldType();

        if (type == iType)
        {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Он просто бежит по списку, проверяет его по условию и, если подходит, то добавляет номер этого объекта в список

Вообще возможно сделать такое с Rx? Так как все методы с итерацией, которые я знаю, просто делают итерацию, но без порядкового номера.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Способ Первый***

1) Для начала сделать обёртку над объектом некоего массива этих объектов:

```
class IndexedObject<T> {
   final int index;
   final T value;

   public IndexedObject(T object, int index) {
      this.index = index;
      this.value = object;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return value + " [" + index + "]";
   }
}
```

2) Сама функция с использованием Rx будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public Flowable<List<Integer>> getAllQuestionsPositionsByType(eQuestionFieldType iType)
{
   return Flowable.fromIterable(questions)
                  .zipWith(Flowable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE),
                     (question, index) -> new IndexedObject<ServicePartFormQuestion>(question, index))
                  .filter(indexedQuestion -> indexedQuestion.value.getQuestionFieldType() == iType)
                  .map(indexedQuestion -> indexedQuestion.index)
                  .toList();
                  .toFlowable()
}
```

3) Вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
getAllQuestionsPositionsByType(someType)
   .subscribe(indexList -> {
      // Получили List с индексами
});
```

---

***Способ Второй***

Использовать оператор `compose` вместе с [Transformers.mapWithIndex()](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras#transformersmapwithindex) из библиотеки [rxjava-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras)

Например:

```
Observable
   .just("a", "b", "c")
   .compose(Transformers.mapWithIndex())
   .map(x -> x.index() + "->" + x.value())
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

И вы получите:

```
0->a
1->b
2->c
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, то второй способ подходит только в случае RxJava первой версии, так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, да, из rxjava2-extras этот функционал вроде как убран

Comment: Значит только первый способ подходит. Странно конечно, что у рх нет какой нибудь ровной реализации, вроде как частое явление работа с индексом.